# Host/Create two IRCd Servers

Tags: irc

Is it possible to setup two IRCd servers on one VPS?

Regards.

Comment: voting to close this as this is not related to programming at all!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  That is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply run two instances of an IRCd on seperate ports, or install two different IRC daemons. But, this is not a programming question, as mentioned above, and belongs better on https://serverfault.com/